# SYSENTER with char array loading

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, system-calls

I'm trying to load a char array address as a system call argument which prototype should be

```
asmlinkage long sys_mknod(const char __user *filename, int mode, unsigned dev);
```

so I wrote the following code:

```
char filepath[] = "/usr/whatever/filepath";
mode_t mode = ...
dev_t dev = ...
..
..

asm volatile("     movq    $133, %rax     "); // System call number (64 bit)
asm volatile ("    leaq    path(%rip), %rdi     ");
asm volatile("     movq    mode, %rsi     "); 
asm volatile("     movq    dev, %rdx     ");
asm volatile(" syscall ");
```

I'm not very used to AT&T syntax nor to 64 bit programming, I think the address loading is correct, but the code keeps on crashing the entire system.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *reimplementing* `sys_mknod()`, i.e. making any kernel changes of your own ?
If not, report a bug; nothing you do in userland should be able to crash the kernel, and if the above instruction sequence can do so on a standard unmodified / nonspecial kernel then that's a bug.

Otherwise, your kernel-side code is buggy - most likely just missing the fact that the *userspace address* which got passed is *not valid in kernel mode*. Accessing this address directly will cause a kernel crash.
If you want to access the string there, use `strndup_user()` or `strncpy_from_user()` to transfer the data into kernel space.

Comment: I suppose you're right, there's a lot of work to reimplement the transition between user->kernel mode if you want to stay in kernel mode